Firefox extension to download an image on alt+click
I'm recently migrating from Chrome to Firefox as my primary browser. It's just less hassle on Linux, but I digress.
Previously on Chrome, I have used this (admittedly, very unhelpfully named) extension called I'm a Gentleman to allow me to download image files with a single click while holding Alt. I want the same functionality on Firefox, but a pretty extensive search turned up nothing. All the extensions I found either use drag gestures, use double clicks without configuration options, or simply don't work. Can anyone please point me to an extension that can be configured to do this exact thing? Thanks.
FOSS is preferred but not required.

Rule #0 of question asking: the moment you post a question, you find exactly what you are looking for.
Found this extension: Image Picka. It seems very configurable, including exactly what I want.

